# HP UFT retry after Object recognition error

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft

I've been using HP UFT for a couple of years now and I needed to start scheduling my tests to run during the night which I've sort of managed but I'm getting a few errors when the tests run, usually a 'Retry' will continue the test, it may be that the web site is not rendering quick enough for the next line of code.  Sometimes it will fail randomly, again a retry will work (where I haven't already added a sync point)

So I could do with an 'on error retry', does such a thing exist? or could someone advise if there is a way around this please? perhaps a screenshot of the error would also be helpful so I know where my test is falling over and I can add a sync point or a wait.

Edit: Apologies for not giving enough info..

The error is an application error, and a pretty generic one where UFT cannot find the object to click on e.g.

"Cannot find the 'xxx' objects parent class frame, verify the parent properties match an object currently displayed in your application."

when this error appears I get options to 'Stop', 'RETRY', 'Skip' or 'Debug'

Given that you've (Pranav - Thanks) said 'on error retry' doesn't exist then you've pretty much answered my question, the only other way I can think to get around this is to keep running the tests and add sync points each time I get a problem and hopefully it will bottom out and ease off.

I will also look at recovery scenarios thanks Dave.

Comment: Please elaborate your issue, what sort of error are you talking about (windows dialog box/Application specific) ? - edit your question and be detailed about your issue. btw 'on error retry' doesn't exist

Comment: You should look at Recovery Scenarios.  The UFT manual has plenty of explanations.  If you try setting one up and have issues with that, come back with a specific question and we can help you out.

Comment: His question is very understandble from someone who uses UFT.  A message box comes when UFT cannot recognize an object and there are buttons in the box to select from.  Can you program UFT to automatically 'Retry' when this scenario occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Scenario Recovery for the test

Resources > Scenario Recovery

Create a scenario for Test run Error, this report the test as failed and include the error message in the run report. Allowing your other tests to keep going.

It also has Post-recovery options that "retry the current step and continue".

[Tuorialspoint.com have a helpful reference](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/qtp/qtp_recovery_scenarios.htm)

Recovery scenario reduces the need to add a check point after most lines of code :) thanks UFT.